# Tree Panel delay in expand after hiding

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect, treepanel

I have a Main View Port with Border Layout with four regions in it

The north region there is a Header which is panel.
The South region is footer which is a panel.
The East region is also panel.
The West region there is Tree Panel.

**[fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7in)**

```
Ext.define('projectName.view.mainView', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

requires: [
    'projectName.view.header',
    'projectName.view.navigation',
    'projectName.view.searchContent',
    'projectName.view.content',
    'projectName.view.footer',
    'Ext.tree.Panel'
],

itemId: 'mainView',
layout: 'border',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                cls: 'mainContainer',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'appHeader',
                        height: 100,
                        region: 'north'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'navigation',
                        region: 'west'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'searchContent',
                        region: 'west'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'content',
                        region: 'center'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'footer',
                        region: 'south'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

For Tree Panel the code is as shown below.

```
Ext.define('projectName.view.navigation', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.navigation',

requires: [
    'Ext.tree.View'
],

width: 295,
animCollapse: true,
collapsed: true,
collapsible: true,
hideCollapseTool: true,
title: 'Menu',
titleCollapse: false,
store: 'navigationStore',
rootVisible: false,

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        viewConfig: {

        }
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

By the above setting of config the Tree panel should collapse / expand by click on title.
But now I want to hide the panel on click of leaf in the Tree.
The code shown below is written in navigation selection change i.e tree panel selection change.

```
var record = records[0],
text = record.get('text'),
xtype = record.get('id'),
alias = 'widget.' + xtype,
searchContentPanel = this.getSearchContent(),
contentPanel = this.getContent(),
cmp;

if (xtype && record.isLeaf()) {
searchContentPanel.removeAll(true);

contentPanel.removeAll(true);
var className = Ext.ClassManager.getNameByAlias(alias);
var ViewClass = Ext.ClassManager.get(className);

cmp = new ViewClass();
searchContentPanel.add(cmp);
if (cmp.floating) {
    cmp.show();
}
var navigation = this.getNavigation();
navigation.hide();
```

}

On click of leaf tree panel will hide
But after hiding if I click the title of panel immediately the collapsed panel wont expand immediately.
It will expand on click after 1-2 seconds of hiding.
I wanted to know the reason and solution for this.

**[fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7in)**

Please help me out with this.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: I am doing it using Sencha Architect3.0

Comment: Hi FreeAslnBeer,
[This is the fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7in)

Comment: I'm not experiencing the behavior (I think) you're describing.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that if you click on a tree's leaf node the Tree Panel collapse's. After this if the menu title is clicked it expands,but moves towards right.I wanted solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a couple CSS rules to override the strange `left` value that's being placed on the div that's generated for the tree panel animation.

```
// Force the tree panel to always be 25px from the left.
// NOTE: `window-1009-body` is dynamically generated, and it's possible that its
// ID will change. You'll want to find a more permanent way to reference it.
// Perhaps add a CSS class to that element, if possible?
#window-1009-body > #treeMenu {
    left: 25px !important;
}

// Override the left value for the dynamically generated div used for animating
// the tree panel.
*[id$='anim-wrap-for-treeMenu'] {
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

Essentially we're changing up the ExtJS structure a bit to add use a valid left value on the treemenu instead of the treemenu's container. I didn't test too much so I'm not sure what else this might affect, bit on first glance things look OK.

Comment: Hi FreeAsinBeer, i used the above solution Tree Panel is coming back to its position, but first it moves to the right and then comes back is there any solution that it wont move towards right.

Comment: yes i dont want it to animate towards the right i just want it to expand similarly how it expand on the first click.